# Print Binary Tree with Empty Nodes

Tags: c#, c++

Is there a way for me to print a binary tree level by level while displaying a NULL every time there is an empty node?

For example, let's say we have [this tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CkXJ.png):

And the output should look like this:

```
A
B C
D NULL E F
```

How should I go about writing the code to produce said output with the tree? Thanks in advance. This is my first post here. Sorry if the formatting and syntax is off.

Comment: You don't show any code for us to help you modify. I would just use the null coleascing operator: `leaf?.ToString() ?? "NULL"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The ideas and algorithmic concepts exposed are more important here, than what technology you apply. That being said:**

**C++ Answer (easily portable to C#):**

Assuming a classical Binary Tree structure similar to this:

```
struct node {
   char data;
   node* left;
   node* right;
}

// Function to print each level in the tree*
void printByLevel(node* root) { // Copy root node, pass by value.
   int height = height(root); // Get tree height. Total amount of levels to print.
   for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
       printLevel(root, i);
       std::cout << std::endl; // A line after each level is printed.
   }
}
```

You will need the **auxiliary** function below, as well as function for computing your tree height to be able to execute the function above.

```
// Print nodes at ONE specific level
void printLevel(node* root, int level) { // Copy root node, pass by value.
    if (root != nullptr) {
       if (level == 1)
          std::cout << root->data << ' ';
       else if (level > 1) {
          printLevel(root->left, level-1);
          printLevel(root->right, level-1);
       }
    }
    std::cout << "NULL" << ' '; // No value, print "NULL"
}
```